# How to align buttons in cards vertically in center in React using Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have made 3 cards in ReactJS using material-ui, so the problem I am facing is that the first card's paragraph is small and the second and third card's paragraph is a bit bigger so when I am placing my button the position of the button differ in all the 3 cards and because of that each paragraph buttons are not aligned properly in vertically center.

I have attached the image of the problem I am facing.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkGVc.jpg

> > Here is the CodeSandBox link :-https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-sanderson-yp491?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Below is my ReactJS and material-ui code

```js
const Room = ({room}) => {
    const classes = useStyles() ;
    return (
    <Card className={classes.root}className={classes.cards}>
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={room.image} title={room.name}/>
        <CardContent>
                  <div className={classes.CardContent}>
                      <h2>{room.name}</h2>     
                <Typography>
                    {room.description}
                </Typography>
                 </div>
                 <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" justify="space-around">
                Primary
            </Button>
                  </CardContent> 
                  <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.CardActions}>
                  </CardActions>

    </Card>
    )
}
```

style.js

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default makeStyles(() => ({
    media: {
    height: 280,
  },
  cards:{
    height:600
  },
  cardContent: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  cardActions: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  buttons: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  h5:{
    fontfamily: 'Ubuntu',
  },

}));
```

How can I align those buttons in each card vertically in the center while keeping the size of the paragraph the same?

Comment: please create a sandbox (https://codesandbox.com)

Comment: @AmareshSM Here is codesandbox link:-https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-sanderson-yp491?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by vertically in the center. Where should the buttons be positioned? From a UX point of view I think the current behavior is not that bad. As a potential solution maybe you could set a fixed height for the description paragraphs and add a button to expand the text or a scrollbar (most likely a slim scroll bar, not the native one).

Comment: @adrianmanduc Thanks Man!! for the idea it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, if I understand well what you're trying to achieve, one possible solution would be to have the description have a fixed height. You can then add a scrollbar to it, and therefore the buttons will be aligned. Alternatively, instead of the scrollbar you could use a "show more" button to expand the content.

I have updated the codepen with an example using the browser native scrollbar - [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-hill-u6l4t?file=/src/styles.js)

To enhance the solution you could look into using a slim scrollbar solution, such as [react-perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perfect-scrollbar)

Comment: Thanks !! for the more enhanced solution :)